# Using std::List with object pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

I am writing a quad tree which stores pointers to collidable objects in an stl list.
I want the quad tree to be able to move the objects from node to node depending on their position in the world, and would like to just get something confirmed:

If I remove the pointer from the list, to insert the object into another tree node (such as the parent tree node), will the destructor for the pointed-to object be called? For clarification, I do not want the object destroyed, as it is used & managed elsewhere in the program.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual object in the list (i.e. the *pointer*) will be destructed, but not what the pointer points to.

It might be a little confusing to begin with, but if you see the pointer, and what it points to, as completely separate entities it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this was the case. My worries are for naught. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The destruction of an object is determined by its *storage duration*. If an object has automatic storage duration (like a local variable), it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. If an object is dynamically allocated (using `new`), it will only be destroyed when you do `delete` on it. If it has static storage duration, it will be destroyed when the program ends.

If you are just copying the pointer out of one node and into another and as long as the object it points at hasn't been destroyed according to the above rules, the pointer will continue to point at the same valid object.

Answer (score 1):

no, destructors are never called on pointers in STL. It only gets destroyed when you call delete explicitly on the object pointed to (or if the object when stored on the stack goes out of scope) or if you use smart pointers.

Comment: This is not quite right. First of all, it's not the *pointer* that is destroyed when you `delete` it; it's the object it points at. Secondly, the object that a pointer points at can be destroyed without using `delete`. Consider `int* p; { int x = 0; p = &x; }`.

Comment: I don't see how that would destroy an object. My understanding of that line of code is that, a pointer is created(p), which is uninitialized, then it is set to point at x, whose value is zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ian It will be destroyed because x resides on the stack, not the heap.  When it goes out of scope, it will be destroyed.

Comment: Ah yes I see now, thanks for clarifying that. I'm a bit embarrassed I missed that...

Comment: thanks for pointing out the unclear answer and missing point about stack allocation.

Comment: @ian Haha, I missed it first as well.  Had to go back and read it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you say will happen, but anyway it might be a good practise to reset your pointer to NULL before deleting the instance. Also, remember to make the pointed-object to be pointed by the correct node, that probably will be the node that was pointing to the node you erased.

Comment: I'm sorry, I find that answer a bit confusing. Do you mean set the list node to null before removal?

Comment: Sorry I'm bad with english :s What i meant is to set the pointer to null before erasing the object that contains it. Anyway I don't think it's necessary considering what others have said.